# ¿Cómo puedo generar el usuario y un arreglo de id de articulos de ese usuario en SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

quisiera saber como pudiera retornar un Usuario y un arreglo de ids de los articulos de ese usuario...

**Por ejemplo, tengo mi base de datos**

Tabla `user`

```
id | name
------------
0  | Juan
1  | Maria
2  | Eduar
```

Y tabla `articles`

```
id | title   | content   | user_id
---------------------------------
0  | lorem.. | lorem.... | 0
1  | lorem.. | lorem.... | 1
2  | lorem.. | lorem.... | 0
3  | lorem.. | lorem.... | 0
4  | lorem.. | lorem.... | 1
5  | lorem.. | lorem.... | 2
6  | lorem.. | lorem.... | 0
```

El retorno del SQL debería retornar

```
name   |  articles_array
--------------------
Juan   |  [ 0, 2, 3 ]
Maria  |  [ 1, 4 ]
Eduar  |  [ 5 ]
```

¿Cómo podría hacer eso en SQL?

Puedo lograr un simple JOIN pero me retorna varios usuarios del mismo id por articulos....

Gracias.

Comment: depende de tu base de datos las respuesta... algunas tienen funciones para eso, otras no.. porque es algo que deberias arreglar en tu programa, no en tu query...

Comment: Mi database es postgresql y no se si tenga funcion para eso... Si la tiene, como se llama? Y bueno, mis intenciones van mas por optimización y por eso requiero que sea el SQL que retorne de la siguiente manera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según tengo entendido, Postgresql tiene una función llamada [STRING_AGG()](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-string_agg-function/). Con ella puedes crear ese tipo de resultados.

```
SELECT u.name,
       STRING_AGG( CAST( a.id AS varchar(10)), ',' order by a.id) AS articles_array
FROM user u
JOIN articles a ON u.id = a.user_id
GROUP BY u.name;
```

Comment: Me sale que el metodo no esta definido o no coincide con los que hay... Tu solución es la correcta por lo que leí en otros articulos pero mi aplicacion no soporta la funcion string_agg

Comment: ¿Tomaste la función antes o después de la edición?